# use variables again after derivation

Tags: subvalues

I have something the following form:

```
a= 3*k;
b=c*d*a;
h[k_]=b*k^3;
```

so if I use `l[k_]=D[h[k],k]` I get `12*c*d*k^3` but I would like to get it in the following form: `4bk^2`

how do I do that?

Comment: You can't really do that without using Hold's and so on, since `b` will evaluate to `c d a` and `a` will evaluate to `3 k` so you end up where you started. Mathematica always evaluates things until it is no longer able to. When you type `b` you'll get back `3 c d k` and not `c d a`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In your simple case, you could use `Eliminate` to get rid of the `c` and `d` in your formula. To really see a `b` in the result you have to hold it somehow, which is really annoying and makes further calculations more difficult. I strongly advise you over-think your approach:

```
a=3*k;
b=c*d*a;
h[k_]=b*k^3;    
Eliminate[{bb==b,dh==D[h[k],k]},{c,d}]//.{rhs_==dh:>rhs,bb:>HoldForm[b]}

(* 4 k^2 b *)
```

Comment: I also get 4 bb k^2, using V 9.01 on windows 7, 64 bit, home edition

Comment: @belisarius @Nasser Ahh, sorry. There should have been a `//.` (`ReplaceRepeated`). I had it but it seems I was delusional, because I removed it in an edit.